# Get results from MYSQL in JSON and use it

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax

I am totally new to JSON and AJAX. I am trying to get a result from a MYSQL query and update a DIV with result. I am using different snippets found online and can get the result JSON encoded but cant seem to do anything with it?

The code or filename API.php to get from MYSQL and output in JSON is :

```
include 'db.php';  
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

 echo json_encode($rows);
```

This outputs like this

```
[{"user_id":"320326","type":"BUSINESS","business":"Business name","f_name":"DAVE","l_name":"TEST","email":"test@test.com","token":"","l_number":"0","m_number":"","password":"work","joined":"2018-07-06","sms_opt":"","instant_opt":"","instant_id":"","email_opt":"","offers_opt":"]
```

The HTML on the page for it to change when its loaded is :

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>
```

And the code to load it and get the information which does nothing is:

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var user_id = data[0];              //get id
        var f_name = data[2];           //get name

        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+user_id+"<b> name: </b>"+f_name); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 

      } 
    });
  });
```

Ideally I would like to test this when a button is clicked and then use the data accordingly, I dont know where I am going wrong and have tried a few things but a lot of online examples are too complex and this is quite basic by the looks of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remove part of the json received from PHP? Because the JSON string in your post is invalid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you receive an aray of objects, you have to iterate it:

```js
var success = function(data) {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
      var obj = data[i];
      html += '<b>id: </b>'+obj.user_id+' <b>name: </b>'+obj.f_name+'<br>'
    }
    $('#output').html(html);
}

success([{"user_id":"320326","type":"BUSINESS","business":"Business name","f_name":"DAVE","l_name":"TEST","email":"test@test.com","token":"","l_number":"0","m_number":"","password":"work","joined":"2018-07-06","sms_opt":"","instant_opt":"","instant_id":"","email_opt":"","offers_opt":""}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>
```

So your JS would look like this:

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
           var obj = data[i];
           html += '<b>id: </b>' + obj.user_id +
                   ' <b>name: </b>' + obj.f_name + '<br>'
        }
        $('#output').html(html);
      } 
    });
  });
```

Comment: This would overwrite the #output html at every iteration  and backticks aren't supported in IE 11 which is unfortunately still supported by MS and will at least be until windows 10 isn't supported anymore (Unless they release a new version like IE 12 for some reason).

Comment: @Lou, huge thanks for editing, looks way better to me.

Comment: Thanks for that but I get TypeError: data is not iterable
    at Object.success (getquotes11:391)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Also whats the best or easiest way to get the data from DB and encode to JSON??

Comment: @wayneuk2, Looks like there was a typo, look at updated answer. Easiest way to get JSON depends on your environment. MySQL can return JSON from v.5.7 (if I remember it well).

Comment: Thankyou, have it working, its not for anything big or major so enough to go on with, again thank you

Comment: And what I meant was you said i received it as object, what is the best way to get it??

Comment: @wayneuk2, you receive it as array of objects, so you can send and receive multiple rows from DB. If you need just 1 row, send the row object. If you need to get multiple rows then use array of row objects. Read more on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) at MDN.

Comment: and sorry to be a pain but trying to add if no match??? I have added 'data: "user_id="+user_id,' to it adding the input from a text field and works but cant put an alert  anywhere if no match??? I dont see a 'if' comment in your code?

Comment: Change `$('#output').html(html);` to `$('#output').html(html || 'no match');`

Comment: Its ok I added  '$rows[status]="ok";' to the query and then 'if(data.status == 'ok'){' to the ajax. It works but is that ok and if no result its just null? It works though?